# Question on notation

Tags: kinetics, notation, units, enzyme-kinetics

[image]

Here, when they write $v/(\mathrm{mol\ s^{-1}\ (kg\ \text{protein})^{-1}})$ is $0.30$ for the first row first column, do they mean that the value is $0.30\ \mathrm{mol\ s^{-1}\ (kg\ \text{protein})^{-1}}$ or $0.30/(\mathrm{mol\ s^{-1}\ (kg\ \text{protein})^{-1}})$?

Comment: $v/x = 0.30$ means that $v = 0.30x$; this applies whether $x$ is a number, a unit, or a collection of units.

Answer (score 2):

The expression
$$v/(\mathrm{mol\ s^{-1}\ kg^{-1}})=30$$
means
$$v=30\ \mathrm{mol\ s^{-1}\ kg^{-1}}$$

This notation is used in the table, so that the entries are all just numbers without any unit symbols.

For an explanation, I copy the following section from my [meta answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2978/7951), which is mainly a collection of rules and examples taken from various standards and guides (see the meta answer for references).

> **Unit symbols are mathematical entities and not abbreviations.** In expressing the value of a quantity as the product of a numerical value and a unit, both the numerical value and the unit may be treated by the ordinary rules of algebra.
>
> (…)
>
> In expressing the value of a quantity as the product of a numerical value and a unit, both the numerical value and the unit may be treated by the ordinary rules of algebra.
>
> > the equation $T=293\ \mathrm K$ may equally be written $T/\mathrm K=293$
>
> It is often convenient to write the quotient of a quantity and a unit in this way for the heading of a column in a table, so that the entries in the table are all simply numbers.
>
> > $$\begin{array}{ll}
> > \hline
> > T/\mathrm K & p/\mathrm{kPa} \\
> > \hline
> > 300.00&3.5368\\
> > 310.00&6.2311\\
> > 320.00&10.546\\
> > 330.00&17.213\\
> > \hline
> > \end{array}$$
>
> The axes of a graph may also be labelled in this way, so that the tick marks are labelled only with numbers.
>
> > do not write “mass [kg]” for “mass in kilogram”

Also note that expressions for units shall contain nothing else than unit symbols and mathematical symbols. Any attachment to a unit symbol as a means of giving information about the special nature of the quantity or context of measurement under consideration is not permitted. Therefore the use of the unit “$\mathrm{mol\ s^{-1}\ kg^{-1}\ \text{protein}}$” as written in the question is not permissible. The correct unit is $\mathrm{mol\ s^{-1}\ kg^{-1}}$.